# Why Head First book uses "/" when forwarding request from Servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets, forward

While reading *Head First JSP and Servlets*, I learnt that forward slash (/) is used to represent **root of Container**. So notice how in [this example from the book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch04s27.html), there is no `myApp` when using (/).

But when they are *forwarding request* (and not using *response.sendRedirect*), they specify (/). Pay attention to the part where they write `/result.jsp` in this picture:
[image]

I am a little confused right now. I have project called `myApp`. And inside it I have *index.html*, *servlet.class* and *result.jsp*.

What I get in the end in browser is http://localhost:8080/myApp/result.jsp. But while reading link I provided at the top, it should be http://localhost:8080/result.jsp. Because as I said (and so did the link), forward slash (/) represents **root of container**. And root is http://localhost:8080 and not http://localhost:8080/myApp.

What the weirdest thing is that it works both ways - if I type *result.jsp* and */result.jsp*. Can someone please clear this, as it is killing me :)

The thing I am mostly confused is how does `/result.jsp` even work, when it should take us to http://localhost:8080/result.jsp and my `result.jsp` is **inside myApp and not inside Container** technically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher-java.lang.String-)

> If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

So the path is relative to your context root, not your whole application server.

Comment: Why couldn't they be consistent with using same "relation" in RequestDispatcher and sendRedirect? So in sendRedirect `/` stands for application server, while in RequestDispathcer it stands for current context root. Did I get it right?

Comment: Also, can you tell me what exactly stands for `current context root`? Can you add in in your answer, please? It is like a project - in this case `myApp`?

Comment: "It is like a project[...]?" I'd say it's the path of an application, more than a project. About why they did it like this, I guess you should ask them :) But a redirect can go anywhere in the server (so it makes sense that `/` is the root of the server), a `RequestDispatcher` (this is also in the documentation) can't refer to stuff outside the context root.

Comment: I guess it uses same principle as <url-pattern> inside XML? So if I write /test.do, it should be relative to context root and not server. Am I right? So `/`is only relative to server when we do redirect. Any close? :)

Comment: I think it's just easier to keep the concept separated. `getRequestDispatcher` handles stuff inside your current context root and is something that has to do with your application/how servlets work, redirects are HTTP stuff. So they behave differently because they handle different stuff.